# Angular URL without # in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm working on a single page web application using AngularJS and Rails.

And there's something wrong with the URL # symbol.

the $routeProvider would add a hash symbol so the URL looks /#/post, and what I want is this: /post
Someone told me add "$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);" this code, and it really works.

But a new problem comes, when I enter a URL like http://example.com/test (didn't exist) redirect to Rails error page said there's no route like this. The problem is that why did the route handle by Rails route, isn't should be handled by AngularJS $routeProvider API?

$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})

It should redirect to the root path but shows an error Rails page. and when I enter /post (exist) it also redirect to Rails error page (no route), but /#/post works fine. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: And if you actually want to get URLs like `http://example.com/test` to work through Angular, here's how to enable HTML5 pushState with Angular and Rails: http://www.angularonrails.com/get-html5-pushstate-working-angular-rails/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS router is responsible only after the page is loaded. The reason why hash tag(#) is working properly is because any pathname after # is not passed to rails. So when you enter `/#/test` it means root path to rails router. But when you enter `/test` rails route will lookup if the route exist or not.

One easy way is to render the same angular page for every missing route.
At the bottom of your route file do something like this:

`get '*path' => "home#index"`